# Secrets getting stripped from aws ecs task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm using github actions to deploy a ecs task definition to my cluster. I'm running into this weird issue where the secrets in the task definition are being stripped out. I'm not sure what is happening or if the problem is on the ecs or github side, but I'm assuming it is on the ECS side since when I create a new task definition or revision manually via the dashboard and using the JSON option, I include the secrets in the task definition and they are stripped out. Then, I have to go into the container via the UI and manually add all the secrets, which seems to work.

When creating a task definition via the JSON option in the UI, is it a feature to strip out the secrets in the definition? If so, is there any way to have this stop happening? Below is an example of my task definition where I use param store:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "myrole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "mylogGroup",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 443,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 443
        }
      ],
      "secrets": [
        {
          "name": "myParamName",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:<myId>:parameter/pathToMyParam"
        },
        {
          "name": "myOtherParamName",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:<myId>:parameter/pathToMyOtherParam"
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "<myImagePath>",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "myContainer"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "1024",
  "taskRoleArn": "<myRolePath>",
  "family": "myTask",
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "512",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stripped out"? You cannot see the secrets from inside the container as environment variables?

Comment: yes. If I don't add them manually (meaning going through the dashboard -> Task definitions -> create new revision -> clicking my container name under Container Definitions -> manually entering in my env variables) they don't appear.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why it was happening? I'm experiencing the same issue...